# How do I build a TWA using @bubblewrap?

Tags: android, node.js, progressive-web-apps, npx, trusted-web-activity

I am trying to build my TWA from a PWA, and I am running into an issue after running `npx @bubblewrap/cli build`:

```
Installing Android Build Tools. Please, read and accept the license agreement
build Installing Build Tools
Warning: Unknown argument --install
```

The licenses have all been accepted:

```
$ ./sdkmanager --licenses
Warning: File /home/user/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
All SDK package licenses accepted.
done
```

The `sdkmanager` I have on my local machine comes with everything installed out-of-the-box, which is why the install command cannot be found. You can only uninstall. So, I thought I could just comment out those lines of code from the local installation of `@bubblewrap`, but that did not stop this from executing.

Please, help! I am at a loss, and have no idea what to do! lol

I have all of the prerequesists installed. Here is my llama file:

```
{
  "jdkPath":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre",
  "androidSdkPath":"/home/user/android"
}
```

This is the `android-sdk` I have installed: `sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just an outdated version of the SDK: https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools

I needed to use the newest Linux distro version instead of an older one I downloaded from a command online that I thought would match Java 8 better...lol smh

It builds just fine now.
Thanks to anyone who attempted to answer!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate your signed APK for your TWA on https://www.pwabuilder.com. We've been working with Google embedding their Bubblewrap tooling on our servers in a transparent way.

Read more: https://www.davrous.com/2020/02/07/publishing-your-pwa-in-the-play-store-in-a-couple-of-minutes-using-pwa-builder/

David